# self referencing schema in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've been through several tutorials. I'm still wondering what the best approach for my problem would be. I got the following Schema:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    _id : Number,
    first_name : String,
    last_name : String,
    friends : [ Number ],
    messages : [{
        from:  Number,
        body : String,
        date : { type : Date, default: Date.now}
    }]
}, { collection : "user"});
```

In `friends` I want to store the ids of user's friends in an array. In `message.from` I want to store the sender's id of a message.

Ideally I want those ids in `friends` and `message.from` to be only ids of valid user entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately mongodb doesn't enforce referential integrity. 
This functionality must be provided by your application.

So in your case: when a user is deleted your application must also remove references to that user in all other user's friends arrays and message fields.